# Storing values from special function registers to a variable

Tags: assembly, embedded, powerpc, isr

I am working on a development project based on freescale MPC5534 controller.
For a certain requirement, i need to store values from two special function registers(namely **SRR0** and **SRR1**) during an ISR(already existing) to variables which can be accessed out of the function. Following is the assembly code snippet for the existing ISR:

```
lis r0,0x_value1
ori r0,r0,0X_value2
mfSPEFSCR r3
and r0,r0,r3
mtSPEFSCR r0 
lis r3,Address@h
ori r3,r3,Address@l
mtlr r3
li r3,0x_value3
blrl
rfi
```

How i am planning to store the values from the registers in the following manner:

```
lis r0,0x_value1
ori r0,r0,0X_value2
mfSPEFSCR r3// move from SPEFSCR register
and r0,r0,r3
mtSPEFSCR r0 //move to SPEFSCR register
lis r3,Address@h
ori r3,r3,Address@l
mtlr r3

mfsrr0 r4 //copy srr0 to r4
mfsrr1 r5 //copy srr1 to r5

li r3,FPU_RESET
blrl
rfi
```

what troubles me is, how do i know if registers r4 and r5 are being used up by some other functions already(say i dont have access to other project files)?
If so, is my approach right? Do i have to explicitly create a stack frame for this ISR pushing and popping r4 and r5, to make sure that there won't be a register clash? Does it make sense?

Right now I am not in a position to compile the file and see.

Anyone who has worked with freescale or powerPC in general might be able to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I remember, r4 and r5 aren't stacked upon interrupt. So how does using them before stacking their old values make any sense at all? I don't see how that problem is related to PowerPC specifically. Generally, you can't just write to random CPU registers from inside an ISR, no matter CPU.

Comment: Any reason to use all assembler code? Why not let the C or C++ compiler generate the framing and use intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search tells me that you need to implement your own stack frame in other parts in this family (555x, 551x). I didn't explicitly find a reference for the 553x, but you should be able to find one.

This is the appnote I referenced: [AN2865](http://www.nxp.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN2865.pdf)